# Mysql not working correctly with and

Tags: mysql

i have the SQL statement:

```
SELECT `id`, `un`, `last_active` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE (`company_id` = :company_id 
       AND `un` LIKE :un 
       AND `id` != :id 
       AND `id` != :id) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

But this doesn't work correctly because i suspect that the repetitive component `id` is not being tested correctly.

So how can i have a sql statement with `id!=1 AND id!=7`

Comment: You might want to look into the `NOT IN` SQL construct: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php

Comment: Yeah i think thats what i was looking for thanks

Comment: Or you can provide different variable names for the 2 id conditions: `AND id != :id AND id != :idtwo`

Comment: @shadow wow i didn't even notice that. i wish i would have done that instead of rewriting my library thanks :)